# Android Device not able to connect to scoket.io using flutter

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, socket.io

am building this very application and I wanted a real-time response, so I decided to make use of socket.io and Nodejs.

During the development process, I noticed my iPhone simulator was able to connect to localhost but my android could not connect to localhost, so i tested in on a real Android device but it could not connect.

The next thing i did was to install different socket_io_client version in my flutter **pubspec.yaml** and as well different version of socket.io in my node **package.json** (server), but none solve my issue

The Next thing I did was to change the Android emulator proxy to 127.0.0.1 and port 8000 and 10.0.2.2 and port 8000 ( port to match with my nodejs server) but this does not work either

The last thing I did was to deploy my code to **Heroku** server, thinking maybe am not able to properly configure my emulator to connect with localhost, but to my surprise, Android emulator could not connect to my running server in **Heroku**

**Flutter Dependence**

```
socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0
```

**Nodejs (package.json)**

```
{
  "name": "prayer_buddy_server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.18.1"
  },
  "author": "zionnite",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "agora-access-token": "^2.0.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

**Flutter Doctor Summary**

```
Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18116933e7 (8 weeks ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
Tools • Dart 2.14.4
apple@APPLEs-MacBook-Air ~ % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale
    en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor
      --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.61.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category
```

*Please pals, what do I need to do to resolve this issue?*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure what the issue.

> iPhone Simulator connect to **localhost via http://localhost:8000**

while

> Android Emulator connect to **localhost via http://10.0.2.2:8000**

so I just place this code on my project like this voila, everything working

```
static String server_ip =
      Platform.isIOS ? "http://localhost" : "http://10.0.2.2";

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('here');

    socket = IO.io(
       '$server_ip:8000',
        IO.OptionBuilder()
            .setTransports(['websocket'])
            .disableAutoConnect()
            .build());
    socket.connect();
    socketListener();
    super.initState();
  }
```